# All solutions of $ z^i = i^z $

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms

In the simple equation

$ z^i = i^z $

how are all complex values found?

$ z= \pm  \,  i, $ and what else?

It can be found by inspection, but to find general solution: We take logs, there is a doubly infinite set, next how to proceed?

Comment: what do you mean ? the solutions of $e^{i \log z} = e^{z i \pi / 2}$ for any branch of the logarithm ? so $i (\log z + 2 i \pi k) = z i \pi / 2 + 2 i \pi n$ or $\log z = z i \pi / 2 + 2 \pi (n+ik)$, and there is one solution for each $(n,k) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$, given by the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe in terms of W-lambert function:

$$z^i =i^z $$

$$i \ln z=z \ln i$$

$$i \ln z = z \cdot \left(i \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$ (considering only principal value)

$$\ln z = \frac{z \cdot \left(i \frac{\pi}{2}\right)}{i}$$

$$lnz=z⋅π/2 $$

$$e^  {z\cdot \pi/2}=z$$

$$[z\cdot (\pi/2)]\cdot e^{[z \cdot \pi/2]}= \pi/2$$

$$z\cdot\pi/2= W (\pi/2)$$

$$z=\frac{W (\pi/2)}{\pi/2}$$

$$W (\pi/2) \approx 0.745407258948051210754871332506528954239850115846378799294...$$

$$z \approx 0.4745409951265112301746794404821....$$

I am sure that equation is multivalued...

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference